# Object::connect: No such signal when obj is returned as shared_ptr

Tags: c++, qt4, shared-ptr, qt-signals

Using Qt's signal & slot, I get error:

```
Object::connect: No such signal FvOverlayPolygon::mouseHoveredOnElemSig(rf::AbstractFvOverlay*)
```

My other `connect`s work fine and I've checked everything I can think of (refered to [20 ways to debug Qt signals and slots](http://samdutton.wordpress.com/2008/10/03/debugging-signals-and-slots-in-qt/) too). Because I personally for the first time use `shared_ptr` for `Qt` for this sample, I suspect there might be something wrong in how I use `shared_ptr`. I really appreciate your opinions.

---

concreteFvOverlay.cpp

```
#include "rf_common/abstractFvOverlay.h"

void FvScene::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *mouseEvent)
{
  rf::AbstractFvOverlay::Ptr item_overlay;
  item_overlay = this->createOverlay(myItemMenu, &pixmap_overlay); // this inherits Class A

  bool con1 = connect(item_overlay.get(), SIGNAL(mouseHoveredOnElemSig(rf::AbstractFvOverlay*)), this, SLOT(mouseHoveredOnElem(rf::AbstractFvOverlay*)));
  }
}
```

---

This overlay is instantiated in this:
abstractFvOverlay.cpp

```
boost::shared_ptr<rf::AbstractFvOverlay> FvPolygonScene::createOverlay(QMenu *menu, QPixmap *pixmap_overlay)
{
  return boost::shared_ptr<rf::AbstractFvOverlay>(new FvOverlayPolygon(menu, *pixmap_overlay));
}
```

---

overlay.h

```
#include <QGraphicsItem>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

class AbstractFvOverlay : public QObject, public QGraphicsItem
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
  AbstractFvOverlay(QMenu *contextMenu, QGraphicsItem *parent, QGraphicsScene *scene);
  virtual ~AbstractFvOverlay();
  typedef boost::shared_ptr<AbstractFvOverlay> Ptr;

signals:
  void mouseHoveredOnElemSig(AbstractFvOverlay *i);
```

For your interest, the reason I use `shared_ptr` here is I want to do interface-based programming (not sure if this is an official way to call this style but what I mean is defining behavior in abstract classes and only for some behaviors I describe them in concrete classes, which Java allow).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use full scope names of types in signal declaration even if you're in same scope. Replace signal `void mouseHoveredOnElemSig(AbstractFvOverlay *i);` with `void mouseHoveredOnElemSig(rf::AbstractFvOverlay *i);` or use AbstractFvOverlay without scope in your connect.

Comment: What you suggest didn't really work out. However, removing namespace declaration for the class AbstractFvOverlay got my connect through (not ideal workaround...I'll figure out more in depth later but good for now). It's not even shared_ptr related...Thanks for insight.